# Dots after word in htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^player/(.+)$ player.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I'm trying to acces a link like:

```
http://example.com/player/..Name..
```

The problem is that the GET variabile returns only **..Name**

How can I solve it?

Comment: do you have any other rules?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem seems to be caused by localhost.